# azure functionapp set meta data on output blob binding

Tags: azure-functions

So i have a basic typescript function app which parses some data from foo.json to bar.json (works like a charm). But i'd like to add metadata to bar.json when everything is said and done. is there anyway you could do something like:
*context.bindings.outputblob.setMetadata({'meaningOfLife':'42'})?*

```
    "bindings": [
      {
        "name": "inputBlob",
        "direction": "in",
        "type": "blobTrigger",
        "dataType": "string",
        "path": "foo.json",
        "connection": "STORAGE_CONNECTION"
      },
      {
        "name": "outputblob",
        "direction": "out",
        "type": "blob",
        "path":"bar.json",
        "connection": "STORAGE_CONNECTION"
      }
    ],
    "scriptFile": "../dist/stuffconvert/index.js"
  }
```

Comment: I suggest you to use blob storage SDK to achieve your requirement. Binding of NodeJS is not possible. Trigger can get metadata, but output binding can not.

Comment: Hi, any update?

Comment: yes. thank you! used the blob sdk to procced with metadata interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there anyway you could do something like:
> context.bindings.outputblob.setMetadata({'meaningOfLife':'42'})?

No, it is impossible(At least for NodeJS, it is impossible to achieve). You cannot bind the output blob binding to the SDK object like in C#.

From the official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#metadata

Only trigger can get the metadata, but output binding can not.

I suggest you to use blob storage SDK to achieve your requirement. Binding of NodeJS is not possible.